# Crystal Reports For Id

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I am new to Crystal Reports.

I want to display 2 ID cards per page. I don't know how to manage fields. I want one name on 1 ID card and Second Name on other. I don't know how to change its location because whenever I try to do that it just shows me the entire list on the both sides.

Just let me know how can I manage the locations per record. How can I make 2 ID cards on 1 page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a group for the ID card key, then add a formula to the the 'new page before' formula under the section expert for the group header.

`not onfirstrecord and remainder(recordnumber, 2) = 1`

Whenever this formula is `true` it will insert a new page. Since it's in the group header, it will create a new page before every other ID card (except for the first card) giving you 2 card per page. You could size the details section to be about half the page height to evenly space the cards on the page.

Comment: thanks for helping . That will work for the shifting the Page but can you help me in formatting the names
Like I want to Create 2 id cards in a single page 
So what I am trying to do is to display AS
------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
ID NAME CLASS ------------------- ID NAME CLASS
1  JOHN 2 ------------------------ 2  MARIA 2
Something like that hope You got my problem

Comment: put the fields and labels on the designer?!?